# Vim: different key mapping for different window

Tags: vim

My .vimrc file has filetype mappings for different filetypes such as :

autocmd FileType sh map gf ...
autocmd FileType ruby map gf ...

While rewriting a program from one language to another, I have 2 splits, one with a shell script and one with ruby. I would assume that "gf" would take on its mapping based on filetype. However, it can only hold one mapping at a time.

Is there any way to declare a mapping only for the existing file/window. I tried ":windo" and ":bufdo" but they work for all windows or buffers.

Comment: Should questions like this go to Superuser? From the FAQ: "General computer software or hardware troubleshooting, ask on  Super User."

Comment: This site has a large number of questions in the Vim category. In fact, there was a pretty similar question when I posted this. Anyway, I'd like to know if I posted in the wrong place. I certainly got the answer in the first post, whereas no one on unix.com was able to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping hasn't been declared buffer local as it should have. `:h  :map-<buffer>`

Comment: Thanks. It worked great. 
    :help map-local  

gives an example. 

    :map <buffer> ,w /[.,;]<CR>